# Sending other data along with a file using Kombu (carrot)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, carrot

How can I send a file along with other data using Kombu? I'm using rabbitmq as the broker.

e.g. file.pdf along a dictionary {'author': 'user'}

I'd like to do this in a single message if possible. But if you reckon using standard serializers of Kombu, how would you bind the separate messages?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but how about:

```
producer.send({"author": "user", "file": file})
```

or:

```
producer.send(file, serializer=None, headers={"author": "user"})
```

Headers can only be of types supported by AMQP though.

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize it is that simple. Thanks a bunch!